# SAWaring when using a Mixin to make SQLAlchemy Objects

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a mixin that is shared between two models. In it, I have a method that takes a dictionary and creates an SQLAlchemy object, this is raising a warning. The two models are very similar (all the same except for one column that has a relationship to a different table. However, all the column names have the same names.

Here is the mixin:

```
class ConstructionBase:
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)   
    data: Mapped[bytes] = mapped_column(db.LargeBinary, unique=False, nullable=True)
    measurement_date: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    
    def from_dict(self, data):
        if 'module' in data:
            self.module = Module.get_by_sn(data['module'])
        if 'component' in data:
            self.component = Component.get_by_sn(data['component'])
        if 'type' in data:
            TypeClass = type(self).type.property.mapper.class_
            self.type = TypeClass.get_by_name(data['type'])
```

And my two models:

```
class Assembly(db.Model, UtilityMixin, PaginatedAPIMixin, TimeStampMixin, MTDdbSyncMixin, ConstructionBase):
    __tablename__ = "assembly"
    module_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('module.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
    component_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('component.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
    type_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('assembly_type.id'), nullable=False)

    #Relationships
    module: Mapped["Module"] = relationship(back_populates="assembly")
    component: Mapped[List["Component"]] = relationship(back_populates="assembly")
    type: Mapped["AssemblyType"] = relationship(back_populates="assembly")

class Test(db.Model, UtilityMixin, PaginatedAPIMixin, TimeStampMixin, MTDdbSyncMixin, ConstructionBase):
    __tablename__ = "test"
    module_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('module.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
    component_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('component.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
    type_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('test_type.id'), nullable=False)

    #Relationships
    module: Mapped["Module"] = relationship(back_populates="test") 
    component: Mapped["Component"] = relationship(back_populates="test")
    type: Mapped["TestType"] = relationship(back_populates="test")
```

With this mixin I would can do something like

```
fake_assembly = Assembly()
fake_assembly.from_dict({'module':'mod_sn','component':'comp_sn','type':'the type'})
```

However when I do that I get this warning:

```
/home/application/models.py:656: SAWarning: Object of type <Assembly> not in session, add operation along 'Module.assembly' will not proceed (This warning originated from the Session 'autoflush' process, which was invoked automatically in response to a user-initiated operation.)
  return Component.query.filter_by(serial_number=serial_number).first()
```

But the object works, when I print it out it is `<Assembly None>` which is wrong but when I do `fake_assembly.module` it gives the correct module object. And I can add it to the session and commit it just fine. Also, it only throws the error for objects that have relationships to other tables.

In regards to the warning I have been unable to find anything useful, so I have come here to try to learn about it. Maybe the way I am currently trying to do things is bad practice. Any insight or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think somehow you are flushing the assembly when the second lookup occurs:
`Component.get_by_sn()`.  So you connect a module, and then that module includes the assembly via `back_populates`.  Then the second `get_by_sn` triggers the flush of the `module` and the session doesn't know what to do with the assembly connected to the `module` because you haven't finished building it yet and it isn't in the session.

I guess there are a lot of practices.  I would probably consider a better practice to move the `factory` pattern outside the class entirely or second best at least put it on a classmethod.

#### Classmethod factory

This would be added via the mixin.

```py
class ConstructionBase:
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data):
        kwargs = {}
        if 'module' in data:
            kwargs['module'] = Module.get_by_sn(data['module'])
        if 'component' in data:
            kwargs['component'] = Component.get_by_sn(data['component'])
        if 'type' in data:
            TypeClass = cls.type.property.mapper.class_
            kwargs['type'] = TypeClass.get_by_name(data['type']) 
        return cls(**kwargs)

# Called like
assembly = Assembly.from_dict(data)
```

#### Standalone factory

```py
def construct_from_dict(cls, data):
    kwargs = {}
    if 'module' in data:
        kwargs['module'] = Module.get_by_sn(data['module'])
    if 'component' in data:
        kwargs['component'] = Component.get_by_sn(data['component'])
    if 'type' in data:
        TypeClass = cls.type.property.mapper.class_
        kwargs['type'] = TypeClass.get_by_name(data['type']) 
    return cls(**kwargs)

# Called like
assembly = construct_from_dict(Assembly, data)
```